# How can I view images on a PC as and when I am shooting?

Tags: nikon-d7000, tethering, windows-7

I just bought a Nikon D7000. When shooting I would like to be able to see my picture on my laptop as soon as I shoot it when I am shooting portraits. What do I need to accomplish this? How do I connect my camera to the laptop and what software do I need. I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop with Windows 7.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is it possible to shoot tethered with a preview on the screen?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9285/is-it-possible-to-shoot-tethered-with-a-preview-on-the-screen) and [this](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14582/windows-based-tethered-workflow-and-automation-solution)

Comment: Adobe Lightroom offers all you will need, and far more :-)

Comment: This question seems to be asking for instant review, not preview or direct continuation into post processing. Perhaps Eye-Fi with some software would work here?

Answer (score 4):

The phrase you want to google for is "tethering"
It can be wired or wireless.

The cheapest solution is wired, you just plug in a USB cable (if your camera has a USB port, all Canon's do, so I assume Nikons do as well) between the camera and your laptop.

Check the CD that came with your camera, there is probably a tethering utility on it. I know there is on the Canon version.

And as @darkcat said, Adobe Lightroom and other programs can do it.

Note: I've found that while Lightroom 4 works with my 50D, it has some buffering problems when talking to my MacBook Pro with 8GB of ram. After 5 or so shots, it becomes slow and this makes taking shots sluggish. With the Canon bundled program, I can keep shooting as fast as my finger works. I've never heard a good technical explanation as to why Lightroom is so slow.

Comment: Nikon, unfortunately, does not include software for tethering. Camera Control Pro 2 is an extra-cost option.

Answer (score 1):

As Pat Farrell said, you can use [Adobe Lightroom 4](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS67a9e0c3a11b14966badab91285ff688ee-8000.html) for tethered shooting.

You can also use the [Nikon Camera Control Pro 2](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Imaging-Software/25366/Camera-Control-Pro-2.html) which will let you to control the camera remotely.

Answer (score 0):

There are also solutions involving the new eyefi SD cards if your camera supports it. I was slightly amazed when someone was able to do it with their tablet because that seems far more practical for someone that's on the move.